# select unique records from table mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have notification table, which contains notification_id, type, type_id ...
I want to select records which have unique type_id.

I am running this query:

```
SELECT $cols, DISTINCT type_id FROM notification ORDER BY alert_on ASC
```

There is something wrong here. What is the way to do it?

If I do like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT type_id FROM notification
```

then it will work. but, i need all the columns from that table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT $cols,type_id FROM notification GROUP BY type_id ORDER BY alert_on ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT ".$cols." FROM notification ORDER BY alert_on ASC";
```

The markdown for SELECT DISTINC is no SELECT sth , DISTINCT, is SELECT DISTINCT.

Comment: There I updated, i dont know what you want to do with type_id

Comment: I don't want repeated type_id. Thanks. I got my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT $cols, type_id FROM notification GROUP BY type_id ORDER BY alert_on ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_name
FROM table_name;
```